# Angular 14.1.3 with bootstrap 5.2

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I'm having a problem that I can't solve when importing bootstrap into my Angular application.

When I want to import my overridden style elements into a component to use custom variables and bootstrap classes, row-col is not working well anymore.

Unless I set the encapsulation of my component to None, "something I wouldn't want to do" encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.None`

Below is the main .scss style file for my application.

```scss
@import 'fonts.scss';

// General font
$font-family-base: 'IBM Plex Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
$headings-font-family: 'adobe-clean-medium', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;

// 1. Include functions first (manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, ...)
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
// 2. Include custom and overrides variables
@import 'variables.scss';
// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';

// 4. Include any default map overrides here (base colors, theme-colors, ...)
$custom-theme-colors: (
  'k-orange': $k-orange,
  'k-orange-100': $k-orange-100,
  'k-orange-200': $k-orange-200,
  'k-orange-300': $k-orange-300,
  'primary': $primary,
  'primary-100': $primary-100,
  'primary-200': $primary-200,
  'primary-300': $primary-300,
  'secondary': $secondary,
  'secondary-100': $secondary-100,
  'secondary-200': $secondary-200,
  'secondary-300': $secondary-300,
  'aux-green-primary': $aux-green-primary,
  'aux-green-secondary': $aux-green-secondary,
  'aux-green-dark': $aux-green-dark,
  'aux-red-primary': $aux-red-primay,
  'aux-red-secondary': $aux-red-secondary,
  'aux-red-dark': $aux-red-dark,
  'body-bg': $body-bg,
  'body-color': $body-color,
  'primary-bg': $primary-bg,
  'domain-information-elementary': $domain-information-elementary,
  'domain-information-independent': $domain-information-independent,
  'domain-information-experienced': $domain-information-experienced,
  'domain-communicate-elementary': $domain-communicate-elementary,
  'domain-communicate-independent': $domain-communicate-independent,
  'domain-communicate-experienced': $domain-communicate-experienced,
  'domain-creation-elementary': $domain-creation-elementary,
  'domain-creation-independent': $domain-creation-independent,
  'domain-creation-experienced': $domain-creation-experienced,
  'domain-protection-elementary': $domain-protection-elementary,
  'domain-protection-independent': $domain-protection-independent,
  'domain-protection-experienced': $domain-protection-experienced,
);

// Custom bootstrap utilities color (ex: text-custom-color or bg-custom-color)
$custom-utilities-colors: $custom-theme-colors;
// Custom the bootstrap table color (ex: table-custom-color)
$custom-table-colors: $custom-theme-colors;

// Merge the custom colors to the bootstrap default
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);
$table-variants: map-merge($table-variants, $custom-table-colors);

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root';

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 8. Importing Bootstrap SCSS file.
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// 8. Add additional custom code here
@import 'bs-sass-overrides.scss';
@import 'bs-class-overrides.scss';

// Importing Datepicker SCSS file.
@import 'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker';

// import bootstrap icons
@import '~bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';

// hamburgers lib
@import '~hamburgers/_sass/hamburgers/hamburgers.scss';
```

Here is an example of a simplified html presentation to have just the bootstrap elements:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">COL 1</div>
        <div class="col-6">COL 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">COL 3</div>
        <div class="col-6">COL 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result works very well with two rows and four columns without importing "style.scss" or setting the component with an encapsulation to None

But if I import the style.scss in the scss of my component to be able to use variables, bootstrap functions, classes to extend them, ... the result is displayed completely in a simple column. But everything else works well (color, style, theme override, ...) except the row/col

Thanks