# Why importing styles.scss in component.scss breaks bootstrap 5.2 col classes?

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, css-grid

While developing a website in Angular 14 with Bootstrap 5.2 I found that `.row` and `.col` classes work perfectly fine until I import `styles.scss` to this components' stylesheet.

```
navigation-header.component.scss
@import "../../styles.scss"
```

After importing `styles.scss` `.row` and `.col` seem to be ignored altogether. The layout breaks for components that import `styles.scss` but stays put for components that don't.

I'd like to import `styles.scss` because I want to have color variables declared in one file.

`styles.scss` are included in angular.json:

```
angular.json
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```

And bootstrap is imported in `styles.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Project's dependencies:

```
npm list
+-- __ngcc_entry_points__.json@ extraneous
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.2.10
+-- @angular/animations@14.2.12
+-- @angular/cli@14.1.3
+-- @angular/common@14.2.12
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@14.2.12
+-- @angular/compiler@14.2.12
+-- @angular/core@14.2.12
+-- @angular/forms@14.2.12
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.2.12
+-- @angular/platform-browser@14.2.12
+-- @angular/router@14.2.12
+-- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.0.0
+-- @types/jasmine@4.0.3
+-- bootstrap@5.2.3
+-- jasmine-core@4.2.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@3.1.1
+-- karma-coverage@2.2.0
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@2.0.0
+-- karma-jasmine@5.1.0
+-- karma@6.4.1
+-- rxjs@7.5.7
+-- swiper@8.4.4
+-- tslib@2.4.1
+-- typescript@4.7.4
`-- zone.js@0.11.8
```

I tried including `bootstrap.scss` in `angular.json` in `styles` section beside `styles.scss`. That didn't help.

[I found a person with similar problem on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74905004/bootstrap-grid-is-ignoring-breakpoints-when-import-into-component-scss-file). His fix didn't help me. Entire layout broke.

[Another person with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448124/angular-14-1-3-with-bootstrap-5-2). User found a radical fix of changing `ViewEncapsulation` to `None`. Doesn't have answers.